# Annotating every some data in a queryset

Tags: python, django

I am developing with Django and I am looking for a queryset somehow can do this operation:
A queryset which is returning 10000 objects, can calculate the average of each 1000 of the 10000 as well.

the code that I am looking for as my knowledge seems like that:

```
queryset=Model.objects.annotate(part=func(get 1000 objecs), average=Avg('Values'))
```

I know annotate just calculates summary values for each item in the queryset, but in my case I just need  to do it for every sliced part  of the queryset so far.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [**`Window`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) function for this:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, RowRange, Window

queryset=Model.objects.annotate(
    avg=Window(
        expression=Avg('Values'), 
        frame=RowRange(start=-500,end=500)
    )
)
```

Comment: I m using MangoDB as database and window is not supported Among Django’s built-in database backends. Thank your for your answer anyway.